# In Shiny/R how to create tabpanels inside tabsetpanels using map functions

Tags: r, for-loop, shiny

I need to create a panels inside a tabset in shiny using map functions .

The output that I need is one tabsetPanels with 3 tab panels
This is the app:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(


  tabsetPanel('one',
              map(1:3,
                 ~ tabPanel(paste0("panel_",.x))
                  )
              )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not clear why you're using `print()` here. Furthermore, you're printing `x` which is something that the output of the print statement is assigned to, which doesn't make much sense. Perhaps missing some enclosures? Admittedly stylistically, you're also using `glue`  as a dependency to do something that's even fewer characters `paste`d:  `paste0("chart_", n_panels)`

Comment: @socialscientist thanks for your time. Yes, I've been studying about functions with for loops. My idea with `print` was to print the  results panels on the UI/screen of my app. I think the main question here is how to create the panels inside the `tabsetPanel` usinf or loop.

Comment: If you can provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of what, say, 2 iterations of the loop should produce then I can help. The loop will just automate the creation of an arbitrary number of panels, providing manual examples will help us understand what you're looking for.

Comment: @socialscientist I edited the question. I think this way I can better express what I need to learn.

Comment: This looks to me like it might be a good place to use [modules](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html).

Comment: @Limey thanks for your time. I will use modules on my original code which is really big. But I think my question is simpler than this. How can I create panels inside tabsetPanel functions using purrr::map funciton in UI ?

Comment: What would the desired result look like? 3 tabPanels with the names "panel_1","panel_2", "panel_3"?  What would the argument "one" stand for?

Comment: @Jan what I want is one tabset with 3 tab panels using map function. I will include this on the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `map` function returns a list. But `tabsetPanel` does not expect a list of `tabPanels`. It rather expects that each panel is an individual parameter.

You can get around this using `do.call`. WIth `do.call` you can call any function and pass it's argument as list.

See below:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  do.call(
    tabsetPanel,
      map(1:3, ~ tabPanel(paste0("panel_",.x)))
    )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: is it possible to do the same using other function thando.call?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. You need a way to pass the `tabPanel()` results as list to `tabsetPanel()`. `do.call()` is straightforward to do it. You can ask a question. There are plenty of people here with more knowledge than I have. Any reason why you want to avoid `do.call()`?

Comment: Hi Jan! Yes do.call() is the best solution. Its just about find a second alternative. I believe do.call() is a function that doesnt make part of the knowledge of people that are starting with R,. Fore example, i tried to do the same with for loop but I couldnt